# A* Pathfinding - Stop moving diagonal through tiles

Tags: java, path-finding, 2d-games

I'm trying to get my head around the A* search algorithm and I got a square moving through a maze but the square will travel through two tiles that are touching by the corners. Here is an example:

[Image - Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv7QI.png)

Is there anyway of stopping the algorithm from adding this to the path

```
public List<Node> findPath(Vector2i start, Vector2i goal){

    List<Node> openList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    List<Node> closeList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    Node current = new Node(start, null, 0, getDistance(start, goal));
    openList.add(current);
    while(openList.size() > 0){
        Collections.sort(openList, nodeSorter);
        current = openList.get(0);
        if(current.tile.equals(goal)){
            List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
            while(current.parent != null){
                path.add(current);
                current = current.parent;
            }
            openList.clear();
            closeList.clear();
            return path;
        }
        openList.remove(current);
        closeList.add(current);
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(i == 4) continue;
            int x = current.tile.getX();
            int y = current.tile.getY();
            int xi = (i % 3) - 1;
            int yi = (i / 3) - 1;
            Tile at = getTile(x + xi, y + yi);
            if(at == null || at == Tile.voidTile) continue;
            if(at.isSolid()) continue;

            Vector2i a = new Vector2i(x + xi, y + yi);
            double gCost = current.gCost + getDistance(current.tile, a);
            double hCost = getDistance(a, goal);
            Node node = new Node(a, current, gCost, hCost);
            if(vecInList(closeList, a) && gCost >= current.gCost) continue;
            if(!vecInList(openList, a) || gCost < node.gCost) openList.add(node);
        }
    }
    closeList.clear();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you send the relevant parts of your code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small off-topic: If you do not want to add such tiles to open list, then they must not be considered as neighbors. So the basic question that you should answer creating a pathfinding algorithm - *what nodes are considered to be neighbors in my graph*.

In your case, your *current* tile is not neighbor of *diagonal tile* **if** their **both** common neighbors **are not** passable. For example, for tile {+1, +1} those neighbors will be {0, +1} and {+1, 0}. And so on. So, lets check for it:

```
// code here...
if(at.isSolid()) continue;

if (Math.abs(xi * yi) == 1) {
  // this is true if we're checking diagonal tile
  if ( !isPassable(getTile(x + xi, y)) && !isPassable(getTile(x, y + yi))  {
    // Both common neigbors are not passable
    // So we won't add this tile as neighbor
    continue;
  }
}
```

And method isPassable:

```
private boolean isPassable(Tile tile) {
  return tile != Tile.voidTile && !tile.isSolid();
}
```

Common neigbors always exist if you deal with diagonal tile, so you shouldn't check them for null.

Comment: Thank you for your help, really appreciate